# OS X - How can I share a folder with Windows users (SMB) without sharing my entire user directory?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, file-sharing, samba

I'd like to be able to just have the single shared folder appear in Windows explorer, but somehow the folder + my users home folder (which essentially allows you into the whole machine) is visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In System Preferences -> Sharing -> File Sharing, choose the folder that you want to share. In that list, there should not be an entire users folder. In Windows, connect to your computer as a *Guest*, which will allow you to see what is publicly available. Do not log in with your username. If you connect with your username, you will see your entire home folder.

Comment: Logging in with 'Guest' and no password did the trick. Thanks,